# Can you upgrade a soldered-in CPU?

Tags: laptop, cpu, acer-aspire

I own a Acer Aspire es1-532-c5yw, and it's celeron processor is no where near what I need. I don't have enough money, however, to afford to buy a laptop with at least an i5. I was therefore wondering if you would be able to replace the CPU (that's soldered to the motherboard) with a better one, and if so what would be the upgrade limits?

Thanks,
Owen

Comment: If you have the special hardware required to remove the CPU it might be possible.  Laptop CPUs are not designed to be replaced be the end user.  If you don't have enough money for a new laptop you don't have the special hardware required to remove the CPU

Comment: Soldered in CPUs are not a retail item so you would likely have difficulty obtaining one, and you would be paying a premium price for it. A CPU that is compatible and not overwhelm the cooling system is likely to be only a minor upgrade. Replacing such a CPU requires special equipment and considerable skill to use it. The cost of the CPU plus that to replace it would approach that of a new laptop, and you would likely have only a minor upgrade. Laptops are not upgrade friendly. A new laptop is the only practical solution.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that [Hardware Recommendations (Stack Exchange Site)](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be a more appropriate place to be asking about upgrading options.  Note: It may also be helpful to note what motherboard your laptop is using.

Of course a CPU can be replaced.  Removing the solder may be needed.

Note: I'm *not* saying that *you* can do it.  (That would depend on your skill/resources.)  I'm not saying that *you* have the necessary equipment.  And I'm *not* saying that it can be done easily.

In fact, I wouldn't expect this to be easy.  Having worked a bit with solder, I almost certainly would not attempt it myself.

For a desktop, I would explore the feasibility of replacing the entire motherboard over an issue like a CPU that isn't designed to be easily removable.

The unfortunate part about laptops is that they tend to have very customized designs, and (because of these designs which aren't standardized) most laptop cases are not designed to accommodate a large number of motherboard styles.  So although I may be able to do so for a desktop, the usual solution (that I know of) for a laptop is to just live with whatever undesirable aspects may exist until you decide to get a new laptop.

With laptops, you get mobility.  You **don't** get as much flexibility.  This is simply one of the key differences between the entire "laptop" experience and the entire "tower"/"desktop" experience.

Comment: This sums it up fairly well. Can you? Sure. Options will be VERY limited though, especially if right now you are coming off a Celeron. SHOULD you? Probably not. Laptops are not fun for this stuff unless you are very savvy for soldering and electronics.

Comment: In addition to all of this, not even sure a mobo that supports a celeron could support the i5 or better processors.