# Upgrading soldered in laptop CPU's

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-core-i7

I have had a Lenovo u530t for a long time, which has a i7 4500u in it, and I have an i7 6500u in a different laptop. The 2 cpus look to be the same size, my question is, can I take the 6500 and resolder it into the u530t motherboard? Or is that just not how cpus work? It seems like they would be compatible, but Im not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they use different sockets. The [i7-4500U is FCBGA1168](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75460/intel-core-i7-4500u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-00-ghz.html) and the [i7-6500U is FCBGA1356](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88194/intel-core-i7-6500u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html).

If you want more info on changing soldered CPU's in general, there are questions that already exist. Check this question and the one it was marked as a duplicate of: [Can you upgrade a soldered-in CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/1204555/can-you-upgrade-a-soldered-in-cpu)